# How to show only few columns by default in adf tree

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I am trying to render a table using adf treeTable component. The table has got so many columns and I just want to show only few columns by default. If the user selects few more columns from view menu on the panel, then selected columns should be shown but by default when the table gets rendered fro the first time, I want show only set of columns.

Default behavior of the treeTable is it shows all the columns. Please  help in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting disabled="true" for the column does the trick. Found it after little trail and error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using  rendering property on table columns. Tie it with some method (for example in backing bean) which returns boolean value, or some boolean property. In that method you can do whatever checking you need